# How to access an object from a state using vuex

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I was trying to make a call to an api, and save the data in the news object.
The problem that I have, is that I can not reach the data of the object news in the component Home.vue

**store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import {API_KEY} from '@/config/secrets.js'
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state:{
    news: [],
  },
  mutations: {

  },
actions: {
  getData(){
    console.log('fetch data');
    var header = new Headers();
    var config = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: header,
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'default'
    }
    axios('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=' + API_KEY , config).then(responde =>{
    console.log(responde);
    this.news = responde.data;
    })
  }
},
getters:{

},
});
```

**Home.vue**
In this component is where I want to show the data of the request that I made to the api

```
 <template>
 <div>
   <h1>Home Page</h1>
   <ul>
     <li v-for="(content , index) in news" :key="index">
        {{content}}
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</template>

  <script>
    import {mapActions , mapState, mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    export default{
      computed: mapState(['news']),
      created: mapActions(['getData'])
    }
  </script>
```

I managed to fix the problem in the following way
First, add a Boolean variable called:

```
loading: true
```

Then In **store.js** he added the following:

```
   mutations:{
     updateNews(state, posts){
       state.news = posts;
     },
     loadingState (state, loading){
       state.loading = loading;
     }
   },
```

In the function getData I wrote the following:

```
     commit ('updateNews', responde.data.articles);
     commit ('loadingState', false);
```

In the Home.vue component, I made the following change:

```
 <script>
     import {mapActions, mapState} from 'vuex';
     export default {
       computed: mapState (['news', 'loading']),
       created (){
         this.$store.dispatch ('getData');
       }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: If you're going to use Vuex, you should probably take a spin through [the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html). All changes to the state in Vuex are made through mutations. In your action you will want to `commit` a mutation (which you will have to define).

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix the problem.

Comment: Great! Looks like you're headed down the right path now.

Comment: @ChrisPerez would you consider answering your own question?